# Switch between different ROS (Robot Operating System) versions

Tags: ubuntu, simulation, ros, robotics

As a ROS (Robot Operating System) developer, how is it possible to switch between ROS versions within my projects? Different Ubuntu OS needed to be installed?

I have tried virtual machines and dual booting but I did not find that a good solution.

Comment: which versions are you trying to switch between? ROS1 and ROS2? or different ROS2 versions?

Comment: I have sticked to ROS1 yet, I am handling projects with Melodic and Noetic.

Comment: There is no reason to be switching versions on a singular machine. Sounds like you want to use docker containers.

Comment: Actually I do not get it, currently I am using Ubuntu 18 LTS with ROS1 Melodic, while there is Robot in the laboratory which is programmed on ROS1 Noetic. I do not know what to do? It seems, I need to upgrade my Ubuntu system to ver 20.04 LTS and change the programs coded in Melodic. Is n't it?
(I am not familiar with docker to handle these problem.)

Comment: @hamidmanouchehri yes, if you're doing development on Noetic you should be on 20.04. It sounds like a robot is already running 20.04, so you could also just ssh onto that to run things.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using the Ubuntu version that is compatible with both ROS1 and ROS2. Then, you can just switch ROS1<->ROS2 when you are sourcing it.

Another option is using docker, which is more recommended.

Comment: May I ask which version of Ubuntu is compatible with both ROS1 and ROS2?

Comment: Ubuntu 20: noetic + galactic

Comment: This isn't really a helpful answer. Because while you can switch between ROS1/2 versions, nodes use different syntax.

Comment: I don't think OP is trying to use the same nodes for ROS1/2. 
You can not do that! You should rewrite things for different ROS versions.

OP wants to switch projects on one computer.

Comment: @Jun OP said in a comment they want to develop for Noetic on a machine that has Melodic installed, not switch between ROS1 and ROS2.